# Singular and plural of pants, shorts, jeans, etc

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, plurales, número-gramatical, ropa

In English, words like pants, shorts, and jeans appear to be in the plural but really refer to one item of clothing (I don't know what the technical term for it is). To be more specific, you can say "one pair of pants/shorts/jeans."

What is the situation with these words in Spanish? What are the singular and plural of pants, shorts, and jeans? Is "pair of (item)" ever used? How would you refer to a single "leg" of one of these items of clothing?

Answer (score 8):

- The most common word is 'pantalones' (plural) and 'pantalón' (singular). Other types of pants are specified using adjectives: "shorts" will be "pantalones cortos" and jeans "pantalones vaqueros" (also valid in their singular forms).
- As in English, you can use the plural form to refer to one item, and you can also use the singular form. Both forms are ok and have the same meaning, but I think the singular one is a bit less common.
- You can use 'un par de pantalones' (a pair of pants), but not with the singular form.
- A single leg is called 'pernera' (etimologically it means 'a place to put the leg')

Comment: I've found the reason for the plural form: http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-pai1.htm (and thanks :) )

Comment: In Mexico, shorts are often called *short* (and sometimes *shorts*), thus the plural is *shorts* (not *shortes*, as it really should be if it was a Spanish word).

Answer (score 4):

In Argentina it's used in both ways:

> Pasame el pantalón.
>
> Ponete los pantalones (referring to the pair).
>
> ¿Dónde pusiste el pantalón?
>
> ¿Dónde pusiste los pantalones?

IMO *par de pantalones* is starting to get deprecated is normal speech (it takes too long to pronounce), while *pantalones* can refer to the same pair of pants with much less effort, and you can use the plural term in **every** situation, while *pair of anything* may not be always the correct case.

When you have two plants, you just say: *give me the plants*, you are not obsessed with the fact that it is a pair of pants. It's the same for trousers. If you had a stack of trousers, you wouldn't say *give me the pairs of trousers*, it would be just plain ridiculous :)

Answer (score 3):

Coincidentally, this morning I found this article that relates to this question. I will post the part of the article that relates to this question and link the source.

> El Diccionario panhispánico de dudas registra la palabra chor (plural,
> chores) como sustantivo masculino usado en Estados Unidos, Honduras,
> España, Costa Rica, República Dominicana y Venezuela. En cuanto a su
> etimología, obviamente chor viene del inglés short.
>
> La definición, 'pantalón que cubre hasta la mitad del muslo', me
> parece que se pasa de casta, pues está visto que los chores de tela de
> yin que usan peladas y cuchibarbis por estos días en Bogotá, sobre
> medias pantalón negras, no llegan hasta la mitad del muslo.
>
> El mismo diccionario registra también la expresión pantaloncitos
> calientes, como sustantivo masculino usado en Panamá y el norte de
> Colombia, con el significado de 'pantalones muy cortos'.  Yo diría
> que, al menos en el interior del país, ya no se oye la expresión
> pantaloncitos calientes, que sí tuvo su uso a finales de los sesenta,
> cuando las primíparas de la Javeriana nos escandalizaban con ese
> último berrido de la moda.
>
> ¿Por qué cambia el inglés short al español chor? Por lo mismo que
> shampoo cambia a champú. En español la hache de la combinación sh es
> muda, como puede comprobarlo al leer desheredado y deshecho. El sonido
> de la sh inglesa existió en castellano, pero representado por la letra
> x, en palabras como dixo (el actual 'dijo') o caxa ('caja'). Hacia el
> siglo XIV, sonido y escritura habían cambiado a jota. Por eso se acude
> al sonido más cercano, el del dígrafo ch.
>
> ¿Por qué escribe yin, pelada y cuchibarbi en una columna dedicada al
> buen uso del lenguaje? Porque yin, pelada y cuchibarbi son escrituras
> correctas. Las tres están registradas en el Diccionario de
> americanismos, elaborado por la Asociación de Academias de la Lengua
> Española y editado en el 2010.
>
> Yin y yines, del inglés jean, lo mismo que bluyín y bluyines, del
> inglés blue jean, figuran en esta obra académica, y aparecían ya en el
> Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, 2005, y en la primera edición,
> 1995, del Manual de Redacción, de EL TIEMPO. Pelada está registrada
> como 'persona joven', 'muchacha' o 'sardina', usada también en
> Honduras, Panamá, Argentina y Bolivia. Y cuchibarbi, como voz
> colombiana, que significa 'mujer madura que aparenta ser joven y
> atractiva'. Por supuesto, tanto pelada como cuchibarbi son voces
> populares; es decir, inapropiadas para contextos más elegantes y
> refinados, donde nadie se presentaría en chores ni yines.

[Link to the source.](http://www.eltiempo.com/vida-de-hoy/educacion/uso-adecuado-de-americanismos_11090462-4)

**Summary:**

> `Shorts` --> `Chor/Chores` or `Short/Shorts` or `Pantalón corto/Pantalones cortos`.
>
> `Jeans` -> `Yin/Yines` or `Jean/Jeans` or `Pantalón Vaquero/Pantalones Vaqueros` (I've never heard vaqueros personally, but apparently is used in Spain). If they are `blue jeans`, it's valid to `write bluyín` (plural `bluyines`).
>
> `Pants` --> `Pantalón/Pantalones`

I would say that the English words are the most popular and are well understood everywere.