# Translation of "slacks" (dress pants)

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, ropa, vocabulario

What is the typical way in Spanish to refer to "slacks" (or dress pants that you'd wear with a suit or other formal clothing)? Is there a universal way to distinguish them from less formal pants? WordReference doesn't have an entry for it and I don't remember hearing a word for it in my travels.

Comment: Related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1736/singular-and-plural-of-pants-shorts-jeans-etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't heard any special word for that kind of trousers in Spain. I've always heard something like

> Pantalón de traje (for the trousers of a suit)

or maybe in general

> Pantalón de vestir (for smart/elegant trousers)

Comment: Agree. In Argentina, is really common use the expression _pantalón de vestir_. _Pantalón de traje_ isn't frequently used but I heard that sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

Some options that you could use might include:

> - pantalones de vestir
> - pantalones finos
> - pantalones buenos

Often times though—assuming it's clear from context—you can informally refer to them as just `pantalones`. You'd distinguish these from other types of pants because many of them have different informal words (e.g. `mezclilla` for jeans.)

I hope this helps! :)